# Set calendar dates

Tags: react-native

I am using DatePicker and I want to set a calendar date based on other calendar field, if the date of first calendar falls in current month then the date of second calendar should be valid from the date of first calendar (for eg: 1st calendar date is set to 20-06-2021 which is of current month then the second calendar date should allow to add date from 20-06-2021), if the date of first calendar falls in last month then the date of second calendar should be valid from the start date of this month (for eg: 1st calendar is set to 20-05-2021 which is of last month then the second calendar date should allow to add date from 01-06-2021), please give me a solution on how I can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using state suppose you have started your first date picker from 2021-06-20

```
this.state = {date:"2021-06-20"}
```

and then when the user changes the date you update your state by

```
onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
```

now by using this updated state you can start your second date picker by using the current state.

And by assigning it to a variable you can apply any conditional statements that you want.